# Postfix forward mail to named pipe

Tags: linux, alias, named-pipes, postfix

In Postfix I can configure to forward emails to a script in /etc/aliases like

```
mailuser: | mailprocessor.pl
```

If I create a named pipe with

```
mkfifo /opt/mypipe
```

and then change /etc/aliases to write directly to the pipe like

```
    mailuser: | /opt/mypipe
```

it is nothing writing to the named pipe. What am I doing wrong? Or is is not possible to write to a pipe directly?

Answer (score 1):

It might be using the name of your pipe as a command and trying to execute it when using the | syntax.  Maybe try:

```
mailuser: | cat > /opt/mypipe
```